# how to specify a path for a file in repository ( java ) , so that my automation test won't fail

Tags: java, automation, cucumber, rest-assured

I'm testing an API with rest assured, programming language is JAVA, I'm having little issue, the issue is , I have to send an image using rest assured, and it's being sent successfully locally, but when i push it to git , having problem with specifying the path, and  all my tests are run on TeamCity , and I get my cucumber report, report as follows

**java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\nameOfUser\Downloads\38250987.jpeg (The system cannot find the path specified)**

I hope I have delivered the issue  descriptive enough, in case if u have any questions,doubts please do ask your questions, hoping for your help and cooperation, thanks in advance!

the code as follows

```
public static Response SendAnImage(String prodID,Cookies cookies)  {

     File file = new File("C:\\Users\\userName\\Downloads\\38250987.jpeg");
        System.out.println("is file found ---->  "+file.exists());

        Response response = given()
                .multiPart("file", file, "image/jpeg")
                .when()
                .cookies(cookies)
                .post("/api/product/"+prodID+"/file/false");


        return response;


    }
```

Comment: please share your code here, we should use forward slash for path reference.

Comment: thanks for your response , code is shared above @ 
Jayanth Bala

Comment: location should be with forward slash => C:/Users/userName/Downloads/38250987.jpeg. please try i have another solution too

Comment: please could u share with your another solution ? what is that ?

Comment: copy your image to your main program folder and use this syntax. this will give you the current working directory path in across OS. System.getProperty("user.dir");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your file in `src/test/resources` folder, then create a new File like this:

```
 File file = new File("src/test/resources/38250987.jpeg");
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot refer to local files in your tests. You need to include the picture file to your Git repository, load them as a resource in the test and then use the method in REST-assured that accepts a byte array instead of a file:

```
multiPart(String controlName, String fileName, byte[] bytes)
```

Comment: thanks for your response , if u could give me visual explanation with some examples would really appreciate it, i have tried what u told me , didn't work for me , i mean for sure i'm missing something.